# My django dash with ployly works well when i run locally but when i try to upload the website in a google cloud machine, it doesn't work

Tags: python, django, plotly, plotly-dash

i’m facing a problem since 2 months ago and i don’t know what to do.

What happens is that i’m trying to create a django website using plotly to create some graphs. The problem is: i did it locally in my computer and worked well. When i try to deploy this website in a google cloud machine, i have some problems that i will describe below:

I have in my database a lot of artificial intelligence models to predict some variable. Each model has an ID to identify which model i want to predict and this id is given by url. For example: in this picture bellow i have id=3 so my django app will get all the models information to plot the graph and to generate the textinputs.

Website locally working:

[image: WEBSITE LOCALLY WORKING]

All text input displayed are variable and depend on which model I am using. when i run locally, it works.

but not when i go to deploy, i faced this problem bellow:

The first time that i access the page, the django dash gives me that the plot app was not found. After i reload my page like 5 times, the graph is shown and works.

Website on deploy mode working after 5 refresh (or requests):

[image: WEBSITE ON DEPLOY MODE WORKING AFTER 5 REFRESH (OR REQUESTS)]

but when i change the id to 4, for example, the graph that is shown is the graph with id 3, not 4.

[image: WEBSITE ON DEPLOY MODE SHOWING THE GRAPH WITH ID 3 NOT 4]

And there are some cases that my graph doesn’t even appear:

[image: WEBISTE ON DEPLOY MODE DOESN'T EVEN SHOW THE GRAPHS]

Has anyone faced this issue? I don’t know what to do.

my code and github https://github.com/paulohiroshi/Models:

views.py

def models_predict(request, id):

```
cache.get_or_set('my_key', id)

app_teste = simpleexemple1.cria_grafico()

model = Models.objects.get(id=id)

cache.delete('my_key')

return render(request, 'models/pages/models-predict.html', context={'model': model, 'is_detail_page': True, 'app': app_teste})
```

simpleexemple1.py

https://github.com/paulohiroshi/Models/blob/main/projeto/dash_apps/simpleexemple1.py

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When trying to solve issues, I find it helpful to create a separate project as a [mcve] that focuses on the problem. Sometimes that alone helps me figure out what to do. But if not, then I have a clear example that I can show to others to get help.

Comment: @paulohiroshi welcome to stackoverflow. your question describes the issues well, but it's hard for us to help without seeing more of your code. can you include the code you used to create your `plotly-dash` app? in the situation where the plot is empty, there are a few possibilities: the data might not be making it to the figure, or some of the parameters might be wrong, causing plotly to not render the data